# Android device performance drop when display is off

Tags: android, performance, wakelock

I am currently developing an app that uses GCM to send a notification to a number of devices that starts a service to start polling a RabbitMQ message queue and do some processing on each message received. I am using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver to keep the device awake once the service has started but I am seeing a significant performance hit if the device(s) screens are off as opposed to if I keep them on. I have also unchecked the 'Wi-Fi Optimization' option and made sure that 'Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep' is set to Always.

Is there something else I am missing? The service doesn't stop completely, it just slows down whenever the screen goes off. Whether I press the standby button or I let it go off after the set time. The devices are running a mix of Jelly Bean (4.2.2) and Kit Kat (4.4.2)

Thanks in advance!

Added code snippets below. The Worker class mentioned just calls another class that performs some data processing:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentServicece.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Intent Service 'onHandleIntent' method

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty())
    {  
         if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) 
         {
            String message = extras.getString("message");

            if (message.equals(START_PROCESSING))
            {                 
                Worker worker = new Worker(this, queueServerUrl, Integer.parseInt(queueServerPort), queueName, fileServerUrl);
                Map<String, Integer> results = worker.StartWorking();

                // Update the results
                update(results, jobId);
            }
        }
    }

    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: What are the services is doing? Can you share code?

Comment: I guess the devices do that on purpose to save battery. High computing power is normally not needed when the screen is off.

Comment: The service just calls a Worker class that performs some data processing on text files. I have added the code that is creating and releasing the WakeLock